# Scanning and printing strings using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I wrote a code for scanning a string from user using pointers and storing it in another string array and printing that string array. The output is coming quite strange. The first three characters are printed but next characters are coming as random garbage values. Please tell me the error in the code. Following is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str1[8];
    char *p1=str1;
    char str2[8];
    char *p2=str2;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    while(*p1)
        scanf("%c",p1++);
    *p1='\0';
    p1=&str1[0];
    while(*p1)
        *p2++=*p1++;
    *p2='\0';
    printf("The copied string is :");
    p2=&str2[0];
    while(*p2)
        printf("%c",*p2++);
}
```

Comment: what's your input? BTW the reason might be due to the missing terminating null character

Comment: `while(*p1)` but the variable to which `p1` points, was not initialised before you test it.

Comment: I initialized the *p1 pointer to the base element of str1[8]

Comment: My input was : chayan. Output was : cha#$. The last two values were garbage as you can see

Comment: Note too that `scanf("%c",p1++);` will take any newline that you enter. These can be ignored by adding a space before the format spec like `scanf(" %c",p1++);`

Comment: Yes `p1` is initiliased, but what it points to is not. The values in `str1[]` are indeterminate. Moreover, you do not finalise the input with the `'\0'` terminator that the following loop is looking for.

Comment: You are right. Please give me the edited version

Comment: There is much more for *you* to do. You'll have to find a proper way of terminating input such as `while((int ch = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not placing the terminating null character**(`'\0'`) at the end of your strings `str1[]` and `str2[]`. And you are **trying to dereference and check the value which is not initialized** in your first while loop condition: `while(*p1)`

```
printf("Enter a string\n");

do{
 scanf("%c",p1++);
}while(*(p1 - 1) != '\n'); //try the do while loop

*(p1 - 1) = '\0';          //placing terminating null character

p1 = &str1[0];
while(*p1){
    *p2++ = *p1++;
}
*p2 = '\0';                 //placing terminating null character
```

here's the demo code: https://ideone.com/dF2QsJ

> Why have you checked the condition for the new line in the do while condition? And why `p1-1`?

This is because you end the input by entering a `'\n'` which gets stored at `p1` and then `p1` moves to `p1 + 1` at the end of each iteration. So, I check whether a `'\n'` is present at `p1 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

okay,
Why arent you using %s and get the input directly. you can get the entire string rather than looping over each character.

Comment: That's because I'm practicing pointers and wanted to do the simple array and strings problems using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
while(*p1)
    scanf("%c",p1++);
```

checks the contents of `str1` (pointed at by `p1`) before ever storing anything there.  That uninitialized memory might contain anything, so this loop might never execute (if the first char happens to be NUL), or might run off the end of the array (corrupting memory).